# Use get/the_post_thumbnail with Custom Size & Crop

Tags: post-thumbnails, cropping

We know that `the_post_thumbnail()` outputs the thumbnail & that `the_post_thumbnail( array(100,100) )` outputs the thumbnail at a specified size.

And we know that we can use `add_image_size( 'category-thumb', 300, 9999, $crop );` to add a custom image size which we can call using `the_post_thumbnail('category-thumb')` with scaling and cropping applied.

Is there a way to use `the_post_thumbnail` to crop an image when it's displayed?

`set_post_thumbnail_size` could help, but I'm asking specifically if there is a way to do this with `the_post_thumbnail`

This is relevant: [the_post_thumbnail scaling not hard cropping](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/141419/the-post-thumbnail-scaling-not-hard-cropping)

**( if nothing's changed the answer is no )**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there's not a way to do this by using `the_post_thumbnail()`, neither it's recommended.

What you are looking for is cropping the images on the fly. This will cost heavy server resources, especially when you have a lot of images to work with.

But in theory, to do so, you can make a script that takes an image as input, crops the image using PHP, and then returns the image data without saving the actual file. But again, it's expensive.